# persist data between executions of Execute() method of IJob Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, quartz.net

I am working on asp.net MVC 4 project. I have written a job named "AppStartPushNotificationJob" and have scheduled it in Application_Start() method of Global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Application_Start() {

   ..............................

   IScheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
   var jobDetail = new JobDetail("AppPushNotification", null,
                                     typeof (AppStartPushNotificationJob));
   Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeMinutelyTrigger(5);
   trigger.Name = jobDetail.Name;
   scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
   scheduler.Start();
}
```

I want to put some data in session and access it each time in Execute() method of AppStartPushNotificationJob. I can't use HttpContext.Current.Session to store session data since HttpContext.Current is null in Execute() method.

Any ideas regarding how can I implement a session kind of thing between successive calls of Execute() method?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas regarding how can I implement a session kind of thing
>   between successive calls of Execute() method?

You could use the Application state. Bear in mind that it is shared between all users so you might need something in the `key` that will be unique to the current user:

```
application["prefix::key"] = "some value";
```

In this example the `application` instance represents the current ASP.NET Applications instance ([`HttpApplicationState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that you should pass to your background thread when starting it in your `Application_Start` method. Basically that will be the current instance (`this`).

This being said before deploying this solution to a production system make sure that you have read about [`The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). This might make you realize how a bad idea is to do such thing in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Darin. But unfortunately HttpContext.Current is null within Execute() method. So cannot use HttpContext.Current.Application :-(

Comment: Fair enough, then simply pass the Application instance to your background thread when you are starting it in your `Application_Start`. This way you don't need to use `HttpContext.Current`. I have updated my answer to reflect on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep state between job invocations by utilizing jobs JobDataMap, see the tutorial for more details:

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

I've linked to the 1.x tutorial as it seems you are using the 1.x API. I would strongly suggest updating to 2.x series if anyway possible.

As stated before there's the caveat of losing state if you are not using persistent job store (IIS worker process recycle on inactivity or otherwise scheduled). With AdoJobStore you can safely persists data between executions. Though it's not guaranteed that scheduler is running if worker has been inactivated.